# BigQuery - Values referenced in UNNEST must be arrays. UNNEST contains expression of type STRUCT ... at [5:18]

Tags: arrays, google-bigquery

Hello guys this time I came across a new error to group array, I will share with you the schema of the table I am consulting so you can tell me the solution. I tried to use ARRAY_TO_STRING but in this case it didn't work out ...

```
SELECT
    individual_details.gender  AS gender,
    COUNT(DISTINCT profile.owner_id ) AS profile_count_distinct
FROM dataset.profile  AS profile
LEFT JOIN UNNEST(profile.individual_details) as individual_details
GROUP BY 1
ORDER BY 2 DESC
```

> Values referenced in UNNEST must be arrays. UNNEST contains expression
>   of type STRUCT at [5:18]

[image: Schema table]

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`individual_details` is not an ARRAY, but rather STRUCT - so you do not need UNNEST it

Try below

```
SELECT
    individual_details.gender  AS gender,
    COUNT(DISTINCT profile.owner_id ) AS profile_count_distinct
FROM dataset.profile  AS profile
GROUP BY 1
ORDER BY 2 DESC
```