# Unnesting 3rd level dependency in Google BigQuery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I'm trying to Replace the schema in existing table using BQ. There are certain fields in BQ which have 3-5 level schema dependency. 
For Ex. comsalesorders.comSalesOrdersInfo.storetransactionid this field is nested under two fields.
Since I'm using this to replace existing table, I can not change the field names in query.
The query looks similar to this

```
SELECT * REPLACE(comsalesorders.comSalesOrdersInfo.storetransactionid AS STRING) FROM CentralizedOrders_streaming.orderStatusUpdated, UNNEST(comsalesorders) AS comsalesorders, UNNEST(comsalesorders.comSalesOrdersInfo) AS comsalesorders.comSalesOrdersInfo
```

BQ enables unnesting first schema field but presents problem for 2nd nesting. 
What changes do I need to make to this query to use UNNEST() for such depedndent schemas ?

Comment: please provide simplified example of your data and expected result

Comment: I can not use method described here because I have to keep using the consistent schema and too many dependent deep fields.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58920800/unnesting-structs-in-bigquery

Comment: Expected result is exactly same table with changed schema of transactionid to STRING. I usually use CLI method to manipulate schema but I have to use SQL in this case

Comment: "simplified example of your data" was the main part of my comment :o)

Comment: I'll share what I can. The data is the  json values nested like this 
comsalesorders":[
{"comSalesOrdersInfo":{"storeTransactionID":"X1056-943462","ItemsWarrenty":0,"currencyCountry":"USD"}]

Comment: i see only one level to unnest! where is your 3rd or even 2nd levels? you should provide simplified example that reproduce you case - so we can help you without guessing and reverse-engineering your case/data!

Comment: ComSalesOrdersinfo has multiple dynamic changing fields. That's 2nd level. In this example there is no 3rd level.

Answer (score 0):

Given that you don't have a schema, I will try to provide a generalized answer.  Please try to understand the difference between the 2 queries.

```
-- Provide an alias for each unnest (as if each is a separate table)
select c.stuff
from table
left join unnest(table.first_level_nested) a
left join unnest(a.second_level_nested) b
left join unnest(b.third_level_nested) c

-- b and c won't work here because you are 'double unnesting'
select c.stuff
from table
left join unnest(table.first_level_nested) a
left join unnest(first_level_nested.second_level_nested) b
left join unnest(first_level_nested.second_level_nested.third_level_nested) c
```

Comment: How is this method different from my implementation ? I'm still getting error for 2nd level nesting

Comment: edited my answer to provide a general case.  In your example, your 2nd unnest is referring to `comsalesorders`, but when you unnested it you aliased it as `commercialdeliverygrouplist`

Comment: Nice catch. That is incorrect aliasing from my end. I'll rectify that

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand your question, but as I could guess, you want to change one column type to another type, such as STRING.

The **UNNEST** function is only used with columns that are array types, for example:

*"comsalesorders":["comSalesOrdersInfo":{}, comSalesOrdersInfo:{}, comSalesOrdersInfo:{}]*

But not with this kind of columns:

*"comSalesOrdersInfo":{"storeTransactionID":"X1056-943462","ItemsWarrenty":0,"currencyCountry":"USD"}*

Therefore, if a didn't misunderstand your question, I would make a query like this:

```
SELECT *, CAST(A.comSalesOrdersInfo.storeTransactionID as STRING) 
FROM `TABLE`, UNNEST(comsalesorders) as A
```